# Fill area with color

Tags: ios, core-plot

I would like to fill in two triangles located between two CPTScatterPlots.
See attached. [image: Fill area]

I tried areaFill, but maybe that was not intended to be used for this purpose. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please share you code...

Comment: Ashok, see my comment addressed to Eric. The code is straight forward, the key is to set the areaFill and areaBaseValue. The rest is just setting up a regular CPTScatterPlot that has the start and the end point with the same values, so it closes the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `areaFill` is drawn between the data line (whether or not the line is actually drawn) and the `areaBaseValue`. You might be able to make it work with a third plot. Use it to draw a closed shape covering the filled area. For example, to draw a filled triangle, use four data points with the first and last points the same.

Comment: ok. I will calculate the crossing point, I have the two end/start points.. so let me see how it goes. thanks. will be back to mark your answer.

Comment: it worked out Eric. thanks for your help. The key idea as you pointed out was to draw a new closed shape and then set the dataSourceBlueTriangle.areaFill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:<your color>]; and
    dataSourceBlueTriangle.areaBaseValue = CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.);